# how to remove an extra window in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

M trying to create a desktop app but facing some problem while switching between frames using button. Its working all fine but it gives me an extra blank window(consist nothing) when I run my project.
Below is my code. Please suggest me any changes or error in my code.

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class Toplevel1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, top=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        top.geometry("600x450+306+137")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(1370, 749)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("New Toplevel")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        self.MenuFrame = tk.LabelFrame(top)
        self.MenuFrame.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=0.989, relwidth=0.25)
        self.MenuFrame.configure(relief='groove')
        self.MenuFrame.configure(foreground="black")
        self.MenuFrame.configure(background="#400080")

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(self.MenuFrame)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.133, rely=0.067, height=24, width=107, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Button1.configure(background="#00ff80")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''Button 1''')
        self.Button1.configure(command= lambda : self.show_frame(ButtonOne))
        
        self.MainWindow = tk.LabelFrame(top)
        self.MainWindow.place(relx=0.267, rely=0.111, relheight=0.767, relwidth=0.7)
        self.MainWindow.configure(relief='groove')
        self.MainWindow.configure(foreground="black")
        self.MainWindow.configure(background="#808040")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, ButtonOne):
            frame = F(self.MainWindow)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # label of frame Layout 2


# second window frame page1
class ButtonOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Button 1 is pressed")
        label.pack()
         
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Toplevel1(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `class Toplevel1(tk.Tk):` to `class Toplevel1:` and then remove `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`. You are inheriting from `tk.Tk` which creates a blank window that you never use.

Comment: @TheLizzard it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes a window to be created:

```
class Toplevel1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, top=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
...
app = Toplevel1(root)
```

And this causes a window to be created:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

If you don't want `Toplevel1` to be a separate window, don't inherit from `tk.Tk`. Instead, you can inherit from `tk.Frame`, and then you can call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` to add this to the root window.

However, it looks like you're intending for your `Toplevel1` to be the true root window, so you can remove `root = tk.Tk()`. You can then do `app.mainloop()` rather than `root.mainloop()` You'll also have to make a few other adjustments, such as using `self` rather than `top` inside `Toplevel1.__init__`.

Put another way, if you want only one window then *either* inherit from `tk.Tk` *or* create an instance of `tk.Tk`, but don't do both.

Comment: When OP removes `root = tk.Tk()`, it will raise an error: `AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute "geometry"`. So if OP is to inherit from `tk.Tk`, they will also need to make quite a few adjustments to their code.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, that is true. There is more work to be done than what I mentioned. The point is, they should instantiate `Tk` or inherit from `Tk` but not both.

Comment: @BryanOakley it worked. Was over this since 3days and got solution here within an hour. Thanks. That mistake occur as I was learning to make a desktop app and tried to implement designing using page.

Comment: Is it possible to change selected Button color. To change color of button when one pressed it and its frame showed up?

Comment: @shabhnam: on most platforms. OSX doesn't let you change the color of buttons.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh I see..
what if I use label instead?

Comment: @shabhnam: Yes, you can change the background color of a label on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As on tkinter callbacks, tk.Tk in `class Toplevel1` is about the same as `Toplevel1=tk.Tk()` which, in a sesne opens a new window. the third line from whitespace, `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, it becomes useless.